# SQL If-Else in the WHERE clause with conditions based on column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would you rewrite the WHERE clause in this pseudo-SQL?

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  IF ( Col1 <> '' ) Col1 = @Val1
       ELSEIF ( Col2 <> '' ) Col2 = @Val2
```

Comment: You can't use IF like this. IF is a statement which is used to control flow. You need an expression like CASE which is used to return a scalar value.

Comment: What your logic is supposed to be (in plain English)?

Comment: That's right @SeanLange. That's why I referred to it as "pseudo-SQL"  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct equivalent for your pseudo code is:

```
WHERE (Col1 <> '' AND Col1 = @Val1) OR
      (Col1 = '' AND Col2 <> '' AND Col2 = @Val2)
```

This matches in priority order, first on `Col1` and then on `Col2`.  It only moves on to `Col2` when `Col1` is an empty string.

Note:  This version assumes that `Col1` is not `NULL`.  That can easily be incorporated into the logic, if you need to support `NULL` values -- especially with a little guidance on how they should be handled.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly correct.  I needed to add that additional check in the second OR block to see if Col1 = '' otherwise the previous block should take priority.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is possible to do something like this using the CASE function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE 1 =   CASE WHEN Col1 <> '' THEN CASE WHEN Col1 = @Val1 THEN 1 END
                WHEN Col2 <> '' THEN CASE WHEN Col2 = @Val2 THEN 1 END
            END
```

A case function returns a value. So, when 1 = 1, the condition is met. Since the ELSE parts of the case are left out, NULL is returned by the case when the condition is not met. Since 1 = null can never be true, the WHERE condition will not be met.

Sometimes the extra complexity added by code like this is not warranted - it would be up to your exact situation after checking for performance etc.

EDIT: added ELSE parts. These are not needed, but might make it clearer for some.

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE 1 =   (CASE WHEN Col1 <> '' THEN (CASE WHEN Col1 = @Val1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                  WHEN Col2 <> '' THEN (CASE WHEN Col2 = @Val2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                 ELSE 0 
            END)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that I understood your logic correctly.
You want to match on either col1 = @val1 or col1 is a blank string
OR col2 = @val2 or col2 is a blank string.

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  (Col1 = @Val1 OR Col1 = '' ) 
OR (Col2 = @Val2 OR Col2  = '')
```

Comment: This is not really the correct interpretation of my code, so it wouldn't work in this case.